# Best practice for passing Datetime parameter to Web Api

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-core

I have an Api call like whose signature is like below

```
[Route("TaskToDo/{userId}/{dateFrom}/{dateTo}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTaskToDo(string userId, DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo)
```

I can't hit the api call in swagger when i enter date like **'13-08-2020'**
because it assumes that it will expect in DD-MM-yyyy.

What is the best approach to solve this issue..
should i change the method signature and take the datetime in string

or

it should be defined that the api is expected to receive the date in a specific format.

Comment: try passing the date as 13-Aug-2020.

Comment: [This should get you some answers...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing#get-books-by-publication-date)

Answer (score 0):

You can send the date in ISO Format (2020-08-13T00:00) JsonSerializer can covert this to a valid date time.

To send the date in the URL you have to encode it for example:

2020-08-13T00:00 -> 2020-08-13T00%3A00